# Angular 7 app refresh not working on IIS even with web.config configured

Tags: javascript, angular, iis, routes

I'm having a weird behavior with my angular 7 application. Everytime i hit refresh, it loses the track of routes and gives me a 404. I've read in a lot of places about configuring the web.config to fix the issue, but even with it configured I can't get rid of this behavior.

web.config

```
<rules>

  <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">

    <match url=".*" />

    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">

      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />

      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />

    </conditions>

    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />

  </rule>

</rules>
```

module configuration

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    SharedModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AuthModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, { metaReducers }),
    EffectsModule.forRoot(effects),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule,
    environment.development ? StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument() : []
  ],
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: JwtInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: RouterStateSerializer, useClass: CustomSerializer }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I also have this section `<base href="/" />` in the header of my index.html file

Answer (score 0):

inside the folder dist you should have a folder with the name of your project try moving the contents of this folder directly below the dist

Comment: I'm publishing to my IIS/Azure the content of this folder (the one with my project name). In my development machine, when I start the application through `ng s` everything works fine